# cURLnot parsing xml sub tags

Tags: curl

cURL command not parsing all the json xml tags.
when i use the json in the web browser it lists below tags.

```
<buildTypes>
<buildType name="build1">
<builds>
<build number="20" status="SUCCESS" branchName="refs/heads/master"/>
</builds>
</buildType>
<buildType name="build2">
<builds>
<build number="105" status="SUCCESS" branchName="refs/heads/develop"/>
</builds>
</buildType>
```

when i parse the json to curl, it just lists only "buildType"

Is there any way we can parse all the tags using curl?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This is XML (not JSON.

Comment: Yes Alex, it's  XML

Comment: So why are you talking about JSON all of the time? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML is different from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON